# Is there a stats dashboard on cartoDB (now carto)

Tags: carto, web-mapping, statistics, web

I've been looking for an overview of map stats (how many views etc) on cartoDB (now carto). All I can find is the bar charts for each map in the gallery. Is there a page on the site that brings these together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the total map views **from your public profile** (username.cartodb.com). First, click on Maps (username.cartodb.com/maps). Finally, click on the map you are interested in. You will find the number below the map title:

[image]

Take note that **map views are not unique views**. That number indicates the number of times that anyone has opened the map since it was created, it doesn't matter if you opened the map or someone else did, the map view just counts the number of times that the map was opened. The MapView feature is triggered every time that someone open a published map or a map in the CartoDB Editor. It doesn't matter the IP address of the user, it only counts the number of times that someone access/open the map.

Comment: Ok thanks. I hope there are plans to provide more in depth stats.

Comment: Any CartoDB plan has that feature. But if your map is embedded within a website/blog you can use something like Google Analytics in order to get those detailed statistics.